# How do I delete an edited sound from a video using audacity?

Tags: audio, editing

I have a video that has had a voice edited to be much different in pitch, how do i fix this using audacity?

Answer (score 1):

If the voice is all that is going on, you can use a pitch shift to attempt to reverse it.  If there are other sounds mixed with it however, then there isn't really anything you can do without also shifting the sounds that are behind it.

If it is really really different, you might be able to try to isolate it by cuting out frequencies of background noises and run the pitch correct on the stripped down set of frequencies, but it's a long shot.